# GCP equivalent of "deny" permissions in aws policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-iam

Is there a way to deny permissions in GCP custom role?
For example, this is a policy in AWS that denies a set of actions on S3:
{
    "Sid": "DenyS3",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "s3:Get*",
    "Resource": "*"
}
Is there a way to define a similar custom role in GCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In preview circa 2022, yes. But it isn't intended to be used the same way.

You can deny a principal from ever using `storage.googleapis.com/buckets.get` but currently this is not for specific resources and these "deny policies" are attached at the project, folder or organisation level, again not to resources. These are not "IAM policies"/"Allow policies" which are the typical approach and are additive only.

Check the subset of permissions that support deny too.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-access

```
{
  "displayName": "My deny policy.",
  "rules": [
    {
      "denyRule": {
        "deniedPrincipals": [
          "principal://goog/subject/lucian@example.com"
        ],
        "deniedPermissions": [
          "iam.googleapis.com/roles.create"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong in the context asked. Your link is to Organization Policies which is not the same as AWS IAM Policy. Only identities with a Policy role can create/modify these policies. They apply to a Project/Folder/ORG. Org policies can deny an identity from being granted a permission which is not the same thing as denying an identity a permission to a resource.

Comment: Fair point, the equivalent in gcp is different. I wouldn't suggest this is "the solution", just the rest of the story. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

In google Cloud the roles are created based on the format 
`<service>.<resource>.<verb>` which specify the exact role to be performed on Resource.

So if a custom role has to be created then you can either add above specific roles or completely omit them from the roles.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles

Comment: Thank you. How do i specify a permission on a specific resource name, for example:
there is a permission - "compute.images.list", which grants a list permission on all the images. How do i get permissions only on a specific image name?

Comment: @MichaelBalber What is the use case? If your use case is that use shouldn't download the image then compute.images.list is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to deny permissions in GCP custom role?

No, IAM roles are deny by default and are additive only.

> How do i get permissions only on a specific image name?

The classic use case for IAM roles is to assign them to the Google Project. This is why a role grants you permission to all resources of that type for that role.

Google has started to release Identity based access control on resources. This means that you can attach an identity with roles to individual resources instead of to the project. For resources that support this, there is a right-hand side panel that allows you to set permissions.