# How GCP denies like AWS does at OU level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I am wondering how one can prevent access in GCP from Folder level. AWS has concept of OU and SCP (policies) to e.g. deny (intersect) permissions at lower level resources. Now, if GCP is allow-only and additive how can I prevent that users do not get access to certain resources within the Projects?

Also refer to this: [GCP equivalent of "deny" permissions in aws policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590455/gcp-equivalent-of-deny-permissions-in-aws-policy)

thanks.

Comment: You can assign rights at the project level or the resource level. Let's assume that you want to allow Bob to only access to Compute Engine VM A. Do not give Bob permissions to GCE at the project, give him access at the resource (VM A). Instead of trying to show "theory", create a real example of what you need to accomplish. GCP and AWS are so different in how IAM is implemented; do not attempt to compare them.

Comment: thanks but your example does not answer the question. You describe basic IAM process in GCP. That was not my point.

Comment: I did not provide an answer; I provided a comment to help you improve your question.

Comment: is this a comment to improve the question: "You can assign rights at the project level or the resource level. Let's assume that you want to allow Bob to only access to Compute Engine VM A. Do not give Bob permissions to GCE at the project, give him access at the resource (VM A)." ??

Answer (score 2):

In GCP, The effective policy for a resource is the union of the policy set at that resource and the policy inherited from its parent (project, folder or organization).

You can configure restrictions on how your resources can be used with the help of [Organization policy Service](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview)

> The Organization Policy Service gives you centralized and programmatic
>   control over your organization's cloud resources. As the organization
>   policy administrator, you will be able to configure restrictions
>   across your entire resource hierarchy.

Comment: ok thanks. But it looks to me that GCP and AWS behave differently in how they propagate policies down the hierarchy. GCP "allow" type rules apply a merge, AWS applies an intersection. So for the "allow" type rules to me looks that AWS is bit more safe. You can be sure that "allow" rules never grow going down the hierarchy. Even more: in GCP you can disable inheritance "inheritFromParent" to FALSE so that Org Policy will no propagate. I think you cannot force that in AWS..