# Remove basic GCP IAM roles for any newly created account

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp, identity-management

GCP has three basic roles - viewer, editor and owner.

1. When a project is spun up, where are these roles defined? For example, in AWS we know where the IAM roles are tagged for an account or a project. Where does this happen in GCP?
2. Is there a way to remove all of these basic roles for an account. That is to ensure that any account that gets created shall not have any of these basic roles.

Comment: These roles are not assigned to a user that is created. Are available but not assigned. By default when a user creates a project the owner role is granted to the user who created that project. BTW, those are not rules but roles. Can you clarify more this?

Comment: Hello @liteyagami, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

As **@Puteri** commented,  By default when you create a project the **owner role** is granted to the user who created that project.

**Go to GCP Console >> Select your Project >> Select IAM & Admin >> Select IAM >> PERMISSIONS >> VIEW BY ROLES >> *Click on REMOVE PRINCIPAL*. ( If you remove the owner role, this action ensures your created project will not have any of these basic roles).**

**Note :** If you remove the owner role, they may still have access via other roles, or the role inherited from a parent resource.

Refer to [Basic Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFwP6.png):

> Basic roles are highly permissive roles that existed prior to the
> introduction of IAM. You can use basic roles to grant principals broad
> access to Google Cloud resources.

**Go to GCP Console >> Select your Project >> Select IAM & Admin >> Select IAM >> PERMISSIONS >> VIEW BY PRINCIPALS >>Click on  Edit principal (Pencil symbol)**, then you can **Add/Remove** roles like (Editor, Viewer, Browser role).

**EDIT:**

Basically, Deny policies are inherited through the resource hierarchy if you deny a permission at the org-level that permission will also be denied on the folders and projects within that organization and on the service-specific resources within each project.

But, You can add deny policies to organizations, folders, and projects
(you can review or view all the deny policies set on the project through gcloud Command and REST API at the moment).

> To view, create, update, and delete deny policies, you need the **Deny
> Admin role** (`roles/iam.denyAdmin`) at the organization level.

You can refer to the official GCP document about [Deny access to resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-access#before-you-begin).

**Note :** If you have the Owner role at the Project, still you require the Deny Admin role on the Organization to create the deny policy.

Refer to [Permissions supported in deny policies](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-permissions-support):

> You can use some, but not all, Identity and Access Management (IAM)
> permissions in deny policies.

Also Refer to [toto's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2824823/toto) similar Question on [deny access in GCP from Folder level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801039/how-gcp-denies-like-aws-does-at-ou-level?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Michael Balber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4414448/michael-balber) question on [GCP equivalent of "deny" permissions in aws policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590455/gcp-equivalent-of-deny-permissions-in-aws-policy), which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: my apologies with the question, so basically we need to deny user access to these basic roles at the resource/project creation level. It is not role removal but denial of role being assigned to a user. Can you help me how to go about the same at best?

Some references:
1. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview
2. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-access

Comment: Hello @liteyagami, Please have a look at the **EDIT** in the answer, which may help to resolve your issue.